# When to use GiST and when to use SP-GiST index?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-index

I'm aware of the documentation for both of the indexes, but can't decide which one to use.

[PostGIS documentation on these indexes](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#idm2461)

Example:

Let's say we have table data with the POINT attribute that contains coordinates.
And let's also say we want to preview all points on the map to create a marker clustering. (Only inside of the boundaries of data view). As in the figure below.

[image]

---

This data is not balanced I suppose? what does that mean?

So why to use GiST or SP-GiST?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*An exact answer is not possible without testing on your actual data, as this is highly dependent on the data size, structure, corresponding PostgreSQL internals, and the exact queries you intent to use the index for.*

Generally speaking, **it is perfectly fine to assume a `GIST` index is what you want**.

Some basic considerations:

- `GIST` has full operator support, including *(k)NN* searches

  `SP-GIST` doesn't support *(k)NN* as of yet, and supports fewer operators (which is probably not a real issue, though)
- `GIST` isn't overly sensitive to the spatial distribution (*homogeneous/consistently spaced* vs *heterogeneous/blobs of geometries*) and the topology (*many overlaps* vs *isolated distribution*) of your
  geometries
  `SP_GIST` is most effective for *non-overlapping* geometries, and boost searches for spatially *homogeneous* distributions, due to its ***S***patial ***P***artitioning
- `GIST` creation time is rising slightly non-linear with the amount of data it has to
  ingest, but has a an overall stable increase (ballpark figure: 20 minutes for 100 million rows (points; global distribution))

  `SP_GIST` is likely faster for smaller amount of data, but tends to have a significant performance drop after a few hundred million geometries compared to `GIST`
- `GIST` indexes have a non-trivial storage impact (ballpark figure: 5GB for 100 million geometries), but only `BRIN` indexes really make a difference here

  `SP-GIST` has a few percentages less space requirement

---

**However:**

Since it seems you are having *homogeneously* distributed `POINT`s, you *could* definitely try the `SP_GIST` index and see if you get more performance out of it; this is still dependent on other factors that are linked to PG internals, relation and result statistics, though.

**But it will likely be slower if all you filter for is all points within a large bbox, as this is better covered with `GIST`.**

---

Further reading:

- a [presentation](http://slides.com/fxku/sotm19/fullscreen) of an old university colleague; his collection of slides, on different topics, are extremely insightful!
- a [direct link](https://habr.com/en/company/postgrespro/blog/446624/) from said presentation with more details to `SP_GIST`; all other index types are covered, too

Comment: fwiw Paul Ramsey's recent geom index blog post mentions that spgist is most effective when data is _homogenous & non-overlapping_: "Don't neglect the possibility of using the newer SPGIST implementation over the tried-and-true GIST, particularly if your data is relatively uniform and does not have a lot of overlap." https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/the-many-spatial-indexes-of-postgis

Comment: @Avocado You know what, that is indeed a typo in my answer, it should have been *non overlapping*. Thanks for pointing out. Apart from that, the new core SP-GIST implementation looks quite promising!